# Need help advising my life-science / biochem daughter on choice of major, career, and internships

Tags: career-path, early-career, biology, chemistry, biotechnology

My daughter will be starting her senior year of high school and plans to study a biochemistry related field in college. (Makes me wonder if biophysics might be up her alley.) She participates in the school robotics team as the "human player" and doesn't code or engineer, but may be the best human player in the state due to her attention to detail. She is very academically talented, artistic, and will have a large amount of AP credit transfers. As a bookworm, I see her mostly headed towards the researcher type roles.

As a computer science major, my knowledge of life sciences is practically nonexistent as well as professional networks of the same.

I am looking for some pointers for what kinds kinds of jobs various life science / biochem majors kinds of majors at a school like OSU (https://catalog.oregonstate.edu/college-departments/science/school-life-sciences/) translate to, so that she can make an appropriate choice of major.  We've been on a couple of tours already, but they spend most of the time talking about the facilities and don't get have the knowledge and experience to talk about anything too deep.

I am also looking for some recommendations of life science / biochemistry professional societies that she might be able to join to get her some broad exposure to the field.

Lastly, I am also looking to make some local contacts in the Portland, Oregon metro area that might be able to find her a high school internship in the life sciences area.  There are lots of chem majors here, but most of them make integrated circuits. :-(

Comment: Those tours are so annoying! Glad to hear a confirmation of their usefulness from a participant. Especially, when they come to our building and there is no way I can get to the conference room on time... I'm not a biochem student, but we had a panel a couple of days ago focusing on career opportunities in biotech industry. The panelists were: Oregon bioscience association (https://www.oregonbio.org/), Twist Bioscience, Seran BioScience (from Bend), Lazarus 3D (from Albany), Absci (from Vancouver), MSE (from Lake Oswego). Maybe this list of employers and one association can be of help to you.

Comment: And if you haven't tried it yet, check out national labs for an internship. They do K-12 through Ph.D.. But it's not that straightforward to find one. You'll have to go through their websites manually. I don't recall we have any biochem here at Albany's NETL, but PNNL should have it, I suspect. A resume with a national lab record gives an incredible career boost. They have a variety of internship options.

Comment: Your daughter should try to find out where graduates go--what percentage to grad school or industry and if so which ones. I had one parent in medicine and one in entomology. I did physics as an undergraduate and pivoted to a different 'hard' science as a graduate. They didn't worry about giving me any career advice. Don't panic! She's got plenty of time to change/tweak a major.